# Logging users in with Facebook Server-side login doesn't work

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying out facebooks server side login (using PHP), and everything seems to work except from displaying my name. So, I've been following this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/ and everything is just as it's written there. I've gone over and deleted everything twice to make sure it's correct. So when I log in to my site I sometimes get the "The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.", but then I always get the Hello. And right after hello is where my name should have been, but it's not. So it's obvious that the log in and authorize part works, but it won't display my name. Do any of you know what might be wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<?php 

$app_id = "MY_APP_ID";
$app_secret = "MY_APP_SECRET";
$my_url = "MY_URL";

session_start();

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // CSRF protection
    $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
        . $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=user_birthday,read_stream";

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] === $_REQUEST['state'])) {
    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
        . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
        . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);

    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $params['access_token'];

    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
        . $params['access_token'];

    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
    echo("Hello " . $user->name);
}
else {
    echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Personal testing site</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This is a personal testing site, and is not related to *mysite* or any of their upcoming functions/ products. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1:**

I think I might have found out where the error is, but I still don't know how to fix it. So when I'm working my way down the code and trying to echo out specific parts of the code I've found out that the access_token is empty. So, the $token_url works (I think), but when I try to echo out $response or the $_SESSION['access_token'] they're both blank. And when I try to echo out the $graph_url I get "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=", nothing behind the token=, where the access_token should have been concatenated on. I don't know if it's the concatenation that's the problem, or if the access token is empty, but I think it's the last. I've been going over my code time after time, and there's nothing wrong there when I compare it to the one on Facebooks' webpage.

Think you guys can find anything?

**EDIT 2:**

When I echo the $token_url and enter it in my webbrowser I get this error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Do you guys think it could have anything to do with the fact that facebook operates with https, but my site only uses http?

**EDIT 3:**

Here's a picture of my app setup:
*Deleted_Picture*

**EDIT 4:**

Okay, so I've fixed it. The problem was that the url in the app settings had to have that last / , and the $my_url in my code had to be exactly equal to that.

But, I've encountered one more problem. It seems that letters like Æ Ø Å gets distorted somewhere, and the Ø (which is in my last name) becomes (Ã¸) (without parentheses). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check the `json object` has an index called `name`?

Comment: Hi! I just copied everything from their webpage. So i'm guessing it has :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some problem with your app setup. Just type your website url  - http://testing123.feedlobby.com/ in the 'website with FB login url - site URL' field. Leave the 'app domains' field empty. I would suggest creating a new app and setting it up this way, and then using ur new app id and secret.

Also, try to enclose the echo statements inside the html body.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "website with FB login url - site URL' field"?

Comment: Here's a link to an image of my setup: [link](http://bildr.no/image/1396928.jpeg)

Comment: YOU WERE RIGHT!! The problem I had was that the $my_url was equal to: http://testing123.feedlobby.com without the last / which I apparently needed. So it works now ;) There's only one problem. The letters æøå (which is highly common in Norwegian names gets "broken" in the transition, and ø becomes Ã¸Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

did you check your application set up and registration this may be one of the problem.[image]

Comment: Hi! Everything was set up except for "App Domains" (I got an error message every time). Now I have added that as well, and everything is filled out like it's on your example. 
You see, I get the facebook login and authorization, but when that's completed and I'm redirected back, it just says "Hello" without my name.

Comment: But the sandbox mode is set to "disabled". After reading through their tutorials I'm left with the impression that it's supposed to be so... Or?